# Selectize - on change add URL parameter and refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html, selectize.js

URL using "http://localhost:8000/test.html"

I want to change URL to "http://localhost:8000/test.html?countrycode=SG" or "http://localhost:8000/test.html?countrycode=MY" or "http://localhost:8000/test.html?countrycode=IN" based on the selectize value selected.

Also, On select change it have get value and refresh the page.

Thanks

**HTML:**

```
<div class="select-container">
  <select class="custom-select">
    <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
    <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
    <option value="IN">India</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.custom-select').selectize();
```

Comment: I have given example with live demo as well, please let me know if this not helps

Comment: Hey Can you please vote my answer if it helps you, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

solution found for this question:

var urlpath =  window.location.origin + window.location.pathname;
        window.location = urlpath+'?countrycode=' + value;

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
<div class="select-container">
  <select class="custom-select">
    <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
    <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
    <option value="IN">India</option>
  </select>
</div>

$(function() {
  $('.custom-select').selectize({
      onChange: function(value) {
        window.location = $getURLPath+'?countrycode=' + value;
      }
  });
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/jalayoza/uZmcD/88/

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your valuable hints. but, on each change, it adds to the url like test.html?countrycode=uk?countrycode=us?countrycode=us?countrycode=in

Comment: Sorry..  i use like this var $getURLPath = window.location.href;
        window.location = $getURLPath+'?countrycode=' + value;

Comment: Hi Yes on each change it will redirect to http://localhost:8000/test.html?countrycode=MY or SG or whatever contrycode you mention in value of select, I have created demo for you as per my understanding

Comment: Everything works as requrired. But on each change, previous parameter is not removing. new change value getting added to the existing parameter like this "test.html?countrycode=uk?countrycode=us"

Comment: what you are getting in $getURLPath? you just need $getURLPath = 'http://'+ window.location.hostname+'test.html?countrycode='+ value

Comment: var $getURLPath = window.location.href;

Comment: window.location = $getURLPath+'?countrycode=' + value;

Comment: use this $getURLPath = 'http://'+ window.location.hostname+'test.html?countrycode='+ value

Comment: let $getURLPath:any =  window.location.origin + window.location.pathname;
        window.location = $getURLPath+'?countrycode=' + value;